# The RAML file/URL does not exist or is not a valid RAML in Mule Studio for every raml file

Tags: mule, mule-studio, raml, anypoint-studio

I am trying to create new Mule project using raml example file. Everytime I am getting following error :
The RAML file/URL does not exist or is not a valid RAML

Please let me know what does this error mean and when it occurs, what can I do to solve this ?

Comment: how did you create the RAML file? if you did this from the RAML designer within Anypoint Platform, then this should suggest whether the RAML is valid. Only valid RAML files can be used to generate Mule projects.

Comment: Best to share your Mule XML and RAML file here. Possible that there are missing dependencies specified in RAML (via !include), or is simply not valid (not following spec). The problem with RAML are sometimes not obvious, and could be flagging error in dependent files (files referred in !include)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your **.raml** file has **illegal/invalid** expressions or **syntax error**.
Whenever there is any syntax error in the **.raml** file it fail to load in Mule Studio.

The best solution is to check the syntax error/issue in a RAML editor such as online API designer https://www.mulesoft.com/platform/api/api-designer or in a RAML tool editor such as API Workbench ref:- http://apiworkbench.com/
This will help to correct your **.raml** file and will generate all your required Mule flow in Mule Studio once valid file is loaded in studio.

Comment: Is there an error log we can look at My raml is apparently fine in API Designer and Mule Editor and online RAML parsers. It's not acceptable to just say "not exist". We need to see the syntax error to correct it.